# Write to HDFS/Hive using NiFi

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

I'm using Nifi 1.6.0.

I'm trying to write to HDFS and to Hive (cloudera) with nifi.

1. On "PutHDFS" I'm configure the "Hadoop Confiugration Resources" with hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml files, set the directories and when I'm trying to Start it I got the following error:

> "Failed to properly initialize processor, If still shcedule to run,
>   NIFI will attempt to initalize and run the Processor again after the
>   'Administrative Yield Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvicationTargetException"

2. On "PutHiveStreaming" I'm configure the "Hive Metastore URI" with
   thrift://..., the database and the table name and on "Hadoop
   Confiugration Resources" I'm put the Hive-site.xml location and when
   I'm trying to Start it I got the following error:

> "Hive streaming connect/write error, flow file will be penalized and routed to retry. 
>   org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWritter$ConnectFailure: Failed connectiong to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://myserver:9083', database='mydbname', table='mytablename', partitionVals=[]}:".

How can I solve the errors?

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help if you could share the complete error trace for both.

Comment: You should be putting your Hadoop configuration files within the Nifi servers, not adding manually to processors

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman see my post update

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm putting the files in Nifi server just adding to processor to location on "Hadoop Confiugration Resources" attribute on "Settings"

Answer (score 1):

For #1, if you got your *-site.xml files from the cluster, it's possible that they are using internal IPs to refer to components like the DataNodes and you won't be able to reach them directly using that. Try setting `dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname` to true in your hdfs-site.xml on the client.

For #2, I'm not sure PutHiveStreaming will work against Cloudera, IIRC they use Hive 1.1.x and PutHiveStreaming is based on 1.2.x, so there may be some Thrift incompatibilities. If that doesn't seem to be the issue, make sure the client can connect to the metastore port (looks like 9083).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, #1 I'm changed the flag to true and still the same error. #2 yeah, the client can connect to metastore with port 9083 (trying with telnet)